# Node.JS crashes with "cant set headers after they are sent" error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I have a Node.JS based server. One of the functions of the server is to receive a photo from a mobile client and store it in the mongodb. When there is a bad connection, the file upload process fails, the client receives an error and retries, and everything works as expected, but sometimes, after the upload fails, the server crashes with the "Can't set headers after they are sent" error. Below is the error generated by the server: the user is authenticated and then the upload process fails, PUT /v1/add_photo.json command returns error code 400, but it seems that the remaining functions of the add_photo.json are still called - why? and thus, this error is generated, since at the very end, the send_failure function will set the header again. (When a "successful" upload fail occurs - after add_photo.json returns error code 400, no other functions are called, and everything works as expected)

```
3/23/2014 16:6:41 0.0.2 handlers/users.js: authenticate_user:
Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage <anonymous 
        (/floomit/node/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:93:17)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at abortIncoming (http.js:1911:11)
    at Socket.socket.onend (http.js:2010:7)
    at Socket.g (events.js:175:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
PUT /v1/add_photo.json 400 9542ms - 467b
3/23/2014 16:6:41 0.0.2 handlers/streams.js: add_photo:
3/23/2014 16:6:41 0.0.2 data/streams.js: store_file: 
3/23/2014 16:6:41 0.0.2 data/streams: store_file: err:
{ [Error: ENOENT, open '/tmp/4684-1425605.jpg'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path:'/tmp/4684-1425605.jpg' }
3/23/2014 16:6:41 0.0.2 handlers/streams.js: add_photo: err
{ [Error: ENOENT, open '/tmp/4684-1425605.jpg'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path:'/tmp/4684-1425605.jpg' }

http.js:733
    throw new Error('Can\'t render headers after they are sent to the client.'
          ^
Error: Can't render headers after they are sent to the client.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage._renderHeaders (http.js:733:11)
    at ServerResponse.res._renderHeaders
        (/floomit/node/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:69:27)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (http.js:1150:20)
    at ServerResponse.res.writeHead  
        (/floomit/node/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:75:22)
    at Object.exports.send_failure (/floomit/node/node/handlers/helpers.js:78:9)
    at /floomit/node/node/handlers/streams.js:377:21
    at /floomit/node/node/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:428:21
    at /floomit/node/node/data/streams.js:495:13
    at /floomit/node/node/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs/gridstore.js:294:22
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

As can be seen from the log lines above (the lines with date preceding them are printed by my server), the function add_photo is entered, it calls a function store_file, which fails. It seems that the failure happens because the file wasn't successfully uploaded to the server, as indicated by the ENOENT error. Which should just result in an error code being returned to the client and the client retransmitting, but instead the server crashes. This doesn't happen all the time, most of the time the client is returned an error code and retransmits. I event tried modifying the store_file() function to always return the above generated ENOENT error and no crashes occur, the client simply retransmits.

Below is the relevant code from the server:

```
// stream handler
exports.add_photo = function (req, res) {
    var new_photo = new Photo();
    async.waterfall([
        // store image file
        function (cb) {
            stream_data.store_file(req.files.file_image.path, cb);
        },  
        function (imageFileId, cb) {
            new_photo.imageFileId = imageFileId;
            stream_data.add_photo(new_photo, cb);
        }   
    ],  
    function (err, final_photo) {
        if (err) {
            helpers.floomit_log("handlers/streams.js: add_photo: err");
            helpers.floomit_log(err);
            helpers.send_failure(res, err);
        } else {
            helpers.send_success(res, final_photo.response_obj());
        }   
    }); 
};

// stream_data
exports.store_file = function (file_full_path, callback) {
    async.waterfall([
        function (cb) {
            fileId = db.ObjectID();
            fileGS = new db.GridStore(db.db, fileId, "w", {"chunk_size":1024*4});
            fileGS.writeFile(file_full_path, cb);
        }   
    ],  
    function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            helpers.floomit_log("data/streams: store_file: err:");
            helpers.floomit_log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, fileId);
        }   
    }); 
};

// stream_data
exports.add_photo = function (new_photo, callback) {
    var query = {}; 
    query["$or"] = []; 
    async.waterfall([
        function (cb) {
            new_photo._id = db.ObjectID();
            db.photos.insert(new_photo, {w:1}, cb);
        },  
        function (result, cb) { 
            for (i = 0; i < new_photo.streams.length; i++) {
                query["$or"].push({"user":new_photo.streams[i].user,"name":new_photo.streams[i].name});
            }  
            db.streams.update(
                query,
                {"$inc" : {"photoCount":1}, "$set" : {"timestampU":new_photo.timestamp}},
                {w:1, multi:true},
                cb);
        }
    ],
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            helpers.floomit_log("data/streams.js: add_photo: err:");
            helpers.floomit_log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, new_photo);
        }
    });
};

// helpers
exports.send_success = function(res, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    var output = { error: "none", data: data };
    res.end(JSON.stringify(output) + "\n");
};

// helpers
exports.send_failure = function(res, err) {
    var code = (err.code) ? err.code : err.name;
    res.writeHead(code, { "Content-Type" : "application/json" });
    res.end(JSON.stringify({ error: code, message: err.message }) + "\n");
}
```

The send_failure function does not return proper HTTP error when this occurs, I need to fix this, but that's not where the problem is. (just wanted to point it out so that this issue is not brought up here)

Thank you,
Gary

Comment: Why are you setting `exports.add_photo` twice?

Comment: The two functions are different. One is called from the stream_handler file, as indicated by the comment just above the function, and the other one is called from the stream_data file. The stream_handler one performs generic, non database specific tasks and then calls add_photo from the stream_data, which performs database specific tasks.

Comment: Which version of express are you using?

Comment: Also, is the code you included above all in the same file? Or did you add code from several files into that single code block?

Comment: The code is in multiple files, I just combined it here. The express version is 3.4.0